# how to access json data assigned to property in user defined method

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios7

I am working on the google maps where I find the location based on the text entered in the 
  textfield.I have used NSConnection to find the location json and then I assign this json to
  the property in connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method so that I can access the json 
  when it is required but unfortunately I am not getting the data in geocodeAddress 
  method(NSLog(@"geodata %@",geocode))

Can any one help me to fix this issue?

```
- (void)geocodeAddress:(NSString *)address withCallback:(SEL)callback withDelegate:  (id)delegate

{

    NSString *geocodingBaseUrl = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@address=%@&sensor=false", geocodingBaseUrl,address];

    NSLog(@"url=%@",url);
    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *queryUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:queryUrl cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:10];
    //NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    downloaddata= [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    NSURLConnection *connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


    NSLog(@"geodata %@",geocode);
    //[delegate performSelector:callback];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error;
    alldata = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:self->downloaddata
                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                error:&error];
    if(error)
    {

    }
    else
    {

       self.geocode =alldata;

       //NSLog(@"geodata %@",geocode);

    }

}
```

Comment: next time indent your code proper so that others dont have to spend time figuring out your code. That way people can answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection's are normally asynchronous, so geocode isn't set until the connectionDidFinishLoading is called, which won't happen until sometime after geocodeAddress... has finished.  In your connectionDidFinishLoading... you'll need to execute code to cause the UI to refresh with the now valid geocode data.

Alternatively you could use `+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error` to execute the request synchronously, but that would be bad since it would block the UI until the request completed.

Comment: @David.How to refresh the UI in async mode

Comment: That's going to depend on a lot more than we can see of your code.  In this case, it probably means anything you want to put where your NSLog call is should be moved into your connectionDidFinishLoading.  Also note that you'll have to implement more of the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol, specifically `– connection:didReceiveResponse:` and `– connection:didReceiveData:`  I'd really suggest taking a look at the example code in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE